# How to make MongoDB Server start on Linux Startup (CentOS)

Tags: mongodb, centos

I'm using Linux CentOS 5.4, I installed MongoDB now it's availabled as a Daemon and Service

When I execute service mongod start is says : [OK] --> in green as if the service started but when I try to connect to it I find it not working.

but when I try to run "mongod" from the shell normally it starts but if I closed the shell connections it stops.

how do I add it to the start up of the OS ? or how do I run it in the background ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add `/usr/bin/mongod` to `/etc/rc.local` this will make it start with the startup scripts

Answer (score 12):

I think you need to create basic init scripts to start Mongodb as daemon and create mongodb user. Detailed information can be found here: [Mongo DB installation](http://library.linode.com/databases/mongodb/centos-5)

Comment: Thanks a lot nickzam I if had enought points I would've voted up for your answer.

Comment: That link is broken :/